# SSIS-Simple ways to find the value that is throwing an error in SSIS

Tags: debugging, ssis

I am loading millions of data from a csv file to an ole db destination using Data flow tasks in SSIS. I have two tasks in the DFT=> Flat file source => OLE DB Destination.
The data loading is failing due to truncation. whats the simple and easy way to find the value that is throwing an error?

I used redirect to a flat file destination,but that didnt give the value that was throwing an error. It's giving information like Flatfile Source Error Output, Error code, Error Column, Errorcode-description and error column description.
They dont help me much in finding which value is causing the issue.
Can anyone please suggest me? Thank you

Comment: Load it manually into a stage table with all columns NVARCHAR (MAX).  Then do a MAX(LENGTH(COL)) for each column, and compare that to your destination table.  Then you will find out what column is too long.

You could get advanced and use system tables and join to your MAX(LENGTH( )) query but unless you have hundreds of rows this should be fine.  Then keep the script for future user.